# multiple if statements in one if statements in python?

Tags: python

Can I have multiple ''if'' statements in one if statement for example

```
if x>23:
  if x<0:
    if y>59:
      if y<0:
        if z>59:
          if z<0:
            print("happy")
```

Comment: 6 answers stating the same, and not answering the question. They all are correct, but no-one answers OP's question - he wants to know if he can write like this - by the way, yes you can. The answers given so far present information how to avoid doing like the question asks - and do better instead.

Comment: @GrzegorzOledzki Your interpretation of the question honestly didn't occur to me until you posted it. Rereading, it's now not clear whether the OP wants to know whether this is valid syntax, or wants a cleaner way of expressing the same logic. The *'in one if statement'* bit seems to suggest that he's looking for the `and` operator, but your interpretation is certainly possible. Voting to close as unclear for this reason.

Comment: @MarkAmery: well, he says "Can I have..." which is quite clear to me. It would be a different question if it started with "Is the best approach to have..." or even "What's wrong if I had..."

Comment: The way he had it was impossible which is why I edited it to show what a possible valid syntax would look like. I asked him to use the syntax that I showed to tell us what he really wants, but I did not see a response.

Answer (score 4):

Sure, just use `and` to join the conditions...

```
if (x > 23) and (x < 0) and ...
```

Of course, in this example, `x > 23` and `x < 0` are mutually exclusive for almost any common object.  it's doubtful you'll ever get to the print statement.

Depending on the logic, maybe you want `or` instead of `and` in the expression above.

---

Note that at times, you can use python's operator chaining to condense this.  Let's say for example you wanted:

```
if (x > 23) and (x < 42):
    do_something()
```

You could write that as:

```
if (23 < x < 42):
    do_something()
```

Comment: @DSM -- Yeah, I was just updating...

Comment: I'm not sure it's `and`, the conditions are mutually exclusive. Perhaps OP meant to use `or` ?

Comment: Yeah, `or` was my thought too.

Answer (score 1):

Use `or` to connect the conditions:

```
if x > 23 or x < 0 or y > 59 or y < 0 or z > 59 or z < 0:
    print("happy")
```

I'm using `or` because the conditions are mutually exclusive (so `and` is inappropriate). The above reads: if any of this condition is true, then do something.

Answer (score 1):

You can chain your conditions with the `and` keyword:

```
if x > 23 and x < 0 and  y > 59 and y < 0 and z > 59 and z < 0:
    print("happy")
```

But here, `print("happy")` will never be executed because `x > 23` and `x < 0` is impossible (same for `y` and `z`). I think you want to do this instead:

```
if (0 < x < 23) and (0 < y < 59) and (0 < z < 59):
    print("happy")
```

... which check if `x` is between 0 and 23, `y` between 0 and 59 and `z` between 0 and 59

Comment: Because of your missing explanation. Downvote removed.

Answer (score 0):

Uh... How about (this is what your code represents, except it's missing some colons and indentations)

```
if x>23 and x<0 and y>59 and y<0 and z>59 and z<0:
    print("happy")
```

Also, as another answer states: `x>23 and x<0` will never be `True`, so happy will never be printed.

Comment: You should probably read up on the python syntax. A good place to start is http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Note that with the indentation that was required in order to get it to show up properly, the implicit meaning is **and**. However, since you have contradictory conditions (x < 0) and (x > 23) This is impossible. Now that I have shown you the requirement for the formatting, please fix it so that we can see what you really meant.

Remember the requirement for the ":" at the end of the conditional line.

Could you have meant

```
if (x<0 or x>23) and (y<0 or y>59) and (z<0 or z>59):
```

Comment: Don't say impossible.  I can easily construct an object which compares both less than 0 and greater than 23... Of course, the usefulness of such an object is quite questionable ;-)

Comment: @mgilson OK extreeeeeeemely improbable or not in our normal (physical) space time continuum. Is that better?